# Local Node API not POSTing to Mongoose DB

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

Can someone please tell me why my POST method is not saving to my MongoDB via Mongoose?

My Angular controller

```
$scope.saveUpdate = function(id){
    $http.post('/api/entry/' + id)
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.entry = data;
        })
        .error(function(data){
            console.log('There was a problem saving your entry: ' + data);
        });
    // update page with remaining entries
    $http.get('/api/entries').then(function(response){
        $scope.entries = response.data;
    });
}
```

My API

```
app.post('/api/entry/:entry_id', function(req, res){
    if (req.params) {
      Entries.findByIdAndUpdate({
        _id : req.params,
        // the properties we're updating and the new values
        username: req.body.username,
        date: req.body.date,
        income: req.body.income
      }, function(err, entry){
        if (err) {
          res.send(err) }
          else {
            res.send('Success!');
          }
      })
    }
});
```

The submit button in the view

```
<button type="submit" class="btn" ng-click="saveUpdate(entry._id)">Update</button>
```

The updated entry hits the DOM when the button is clicked but when it hits the Angular core code it reverts back to its original state without updating the DB. No errors are thrown either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong in the code above:

1. The entire `req.params`object is being passed to the `_id` field instead of `req.params.entry_id`
2. The way parameters are being passed to `findByIdAndUpdate()` is incorrect
3. The request body is never being sent over in your `$http.post()` but you're expecting the `req.body` to contain data in your route

`req.params` points to the whole `params` object on the request. You only want to get the ID from the params and then pass that into your mongoose model.

Assuming you're passing in the `entry_id` then you will pass your first condition `if(req.params)` since params will indeed exist. However, when you pass `req.params` to `_id` field of your `Entries` model you're actually passing in the whole object `{ entry_id: '123' }` instead of just `123`.

Additionally, the way you're passing in values to the `findByIdAndUpdate` method is incorrect. There are 4 params it will take `findByIdAndUpdate(id, [update], [options], [callback])`, `id` is the only required field. You're passing in the whole object to find based on id and update the values in a single argument. You need to break out `entry_id` from the fields you'd like to update.

```
app.post('/api/entry/:entry_id', function(req, res) {

  // Param Existence Checking
  if (!req.params.entry_id)
    return res.status(400).send('an entry_id must be provided');
  if (!req.body.username)
    return res.status(400).send('a username must be provided');
  if (!req.body.date)
    return res.status(400).send('a date must be provided');
  if (!req.body.income)
    return res.status(400).send('an income must be provided');

  var updateData = {
    username: req.body.username,
    date: req.body.date,
    income: req.body.income
  };

  Entries.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.entry_id, updateData, function(err, entry){
    if (err)
      return res.status(500).send(err)

    return res.status(200).send('Success!');
  })

});
```

Also based on sample code from your question, I don't see where you're passing in values to `req.body` when doing `$http.put()`. One thing for sure is that, if `req.body` doesn't contain `username`,`date` and `income` you would get `undefined` assigned to those fields.

To supply the request body via `$http.post()` pass it in to the second param `data`.

```
$http.post('/api/entry/' + id, {
  username: 'username',
  date: new Date(),
  income: 10000.00
})
  .then(function(res, status){ 
    console.log(res.data);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Additionally, don't use `.success()` in your promise chain, [that approach is deprecated](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice). You should use the A+ standard `.then()` and `.catch()` when handling your response.

Comment: I see what your saying. After replacing `entry_id` to my requestsit's  unfortunately still not updating the DB. It reverts back to the original entry when it hits a `completeRequest` callback in the angular.js core file. No idea why this is.

Comment: @PanicBus see my answer, I've updated the call to `Entries.findByIdAndUpdate()` in my answer. The first param should be the `_id` Value to match which is `req.params.entry_id`. The second param is an object of the fields and their values to update. You are passing your Fields to Update and your ID in one object and one param which is incorrect. [Model.findByIdAndUpdate Docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate)

Comment: I see what's happening. And you were right, `body` is coming thru as an empty object `body: {}`. Would you know offhand why that is, and how to parse the data coming thru from the req? I've got the body-parser middleware included and used.

Comment: That's a good update but now I'm getting this from my controller: POST http://localhost:3000/api/entry/56faf8739777cb3181141b1d 400 (Bad Request)
Instead of hard coding it into the controller I'm getting my data from the form `$scope.entry = data;`

Comment: Ok it's done. Thank you for the help. Added a parameter in the submit button to catch the update data `entry` and passed that into the .post object. 
`$scope.saveUpdate = function(id, entry){..`
`entry.username`
etc